# Which condition on $f$ ensures $\int_{0}^\infty f(t)\,\mathrm dt$ converges $\implies \lim_{t\to \infty} f(t)=0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

As we can create a continuous function $f$ such that $$\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x) \mathrm dx \text{ and } \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)\ne0.$$

e.g. the picewise affine function $f$ whose graph on segment $[n, n+1]$ is:
[image]

$f$ doesn't satisfy $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=0$ but $\displaystyle{\left | \int_0^\infty f(x)\mathrm dx \right | = \sum_{n= 1}^\infty\frac 1{2n^2} = \frac{\pi}{12} < \infty}$

This example shows that $f$ continuous is not a sufficient condition to ensure $\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x) \mathrm dx}$ converges $\implies \displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=0$.
My question is what is the minimal condition on $f$ that ensures this?

Comment: If $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ exists, then it must be $0$. So I guess that is the minimal condition you might be looking for?

Comment: Uniform continuity of $f$ (together with OP's assumption that $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ converges as improper Riemann integral) is enough to guarantee that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 0$. Notice that uniform continuity alone includes, but is not restricted to, the case where $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ converges.